# Special characters on mule filename

Tags: mule, special-characters, filenames

I am using an email subject in my flow as the file name of the output file. however, sometimes there are special characters in the subject line that triggers an error when writing the files to my outbound file endpoint.is there a way to convert it on the flow? or can I force it to write on the endpoint?

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a MEL expression to normalize the subject into an acceptable file name. In the expression, use one of the helper methods available in [`org.mule.util.StringUtil`](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/util/StringUtils.html) to perform the cleanup.